# Xcode Swift MacOS App, disable entering text on NSScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm implementing an MacOS App that open a binary file and I'd like to show some information about the input file (file name, file location, size...).
Is the NSScrollView the right choice? If yes is it possible to disable the entering text feature? I just want my NSScrollView to be auto-scrollable and let the user just to select the text to copy/paste if needed.

The second question is if can I just drag-drop the file into NSScrollView instead of opening the file with the NSOpenPanel Dialog.

Thanks!

Comment: `NSScrollView`: "A view that displays a portion of a document view and provides scroll bars that allow the user to move the document view within the scroll view.". `NSTextField` and `NSTextView` can display text. Add them to a window and play around with the attributes. Drag & drop needs some code, see [Xcode Swift MacOS App, drag and drop file into NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281056/xcode-swift-macos-app-drag-and-drop-file-into-nstextfield)

Comment: Thanks for response, I've started with the NSTextField but I had problem implementing drag&Drop (I'm newbie) and also can't change the text color just for a portion of the text. Switched to the NSScrollView but can't disable the feature that let the user write text inside the NSScrollView....

Comment: Do you mean a `NSTextView` inside a `NSScrollView`? Select the `NSTextView` and uncheck "Editable".

Comment: There is no such property on NSScrollView!

Comment: A `NSScrollView` scrolls and can't display text. Use a `NSTextField` or `NSTextView` to display text. In IB it's "Text Field" and "Text View".

Comment: Maybe this helps: [macOS Controls Tutorial: Part 1/2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/759-macos-controls-tutorial-part-1-2)

Comment: Thanks you so much!